# wordpress widgetlogic conditional logic is not working for post page

Tags: widget, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am just developing a theme under wordpress twentyeleven theme. In that theme I have installed [widget logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin to show different widgets on different pages. But when I want to show some widgets in post page and made conditional tags for widget logic the widgets are not showing in post page.
I have tried some thing conditional tags like this

```
is_page('Blog')
is_page('246') // As 246 is the page id of my post page.
```

I tried all of them but still its not showing.

I had also tried `wp_reset_query();` in my functions.php file. But no luck there was.

**Update**

To make blog page as my post page I have made changes in wordpress `settings >> Reading >> A static page >> Post page -> Blog`

So can someone kindly help me to solve this? I have already spent a day to solve this. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this in your widget conditional

```
is_home(Blog)
```

Here is the link http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/

Just check there `is_home() -- just the main blog page`

Answer (score 0):

try `is_page(246)` without quotes.